# Реализация слайдера

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, анимация

Как реализовать слайдер, такой же как на этом сайте? https://tjournal.ru/36774-bivshii-agent-fbr-sgorel-vo-vzorvavsheisya-v-avarii-tesla[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в чем у вас возникает проблема выдрать слайдер вот с того сайта?

Comment: Хочу понять как он устроен.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/opxcnqa1/